# run killall command in php shell_exec function

Tags: php, centos, shell-exec

I have a working shell script using killall to kill all instances of a program like below:

killall abc

Now, I write a php webpage to execute this script using shell_exec function:

shell_exec('sh ./myscript.sh');

Problem is that my php code works correct on commandline with "php myscript.php", but not works in browsers!. However, I know that the user in commandline is "root" and in php is "apache" (I get this with 'whoami').
The linux distribution is Centos 6 which uses SElinux. I changed the status of selinux to permissive.

### **Things I've checked:**

- PHP safe_mode is off
- shell_exec() is not present in disable_functions in php.ini

Is there a way to run scripts with kill command using php?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any PHP error (check `error_reporting` and `display_errors`)? what is the exit code of executed command (use `exec()` to findout)? do you have permission to `kill` the target process?

Comment: no exit code and no errors are reported! exec () is also has a similar output, yea, I have permission to kill, but "apache" does not!

Comment: there is always an exit code! on success it is 0 and non-zero is error code!when you don't have permission you can't ! when you run it from apache you are apache!

Comment: yea, but the question is how to do this work with apache?!

Answer (score 0):

you either have to run apache as root (insecure) or, which would be much safer, you have to run the commands you try to kill as 'apache', or you configure your sudoers file to grant apache rights to killall command:

```
# vim /etc/sudoers
apache localhost=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/killall
```

and then change the myscript.sh to do sudo killall abc

Comment: Thanks for reply, I add this line to /etc/sudoers file, but the problem is not solved...

Comment: ok, try doing # su apache, and then typing $ sudo killall abc

Comment: it should be /usr/bin/killall in sudoers

Comment: when I type # su apache in command line, the output is "This account is currently not available"!

Comment: are you sure apache is running as user apache? please check what's in /etc/passwd file and which user listed there runs apache, for example on my machine that user is "www-data", or you can do ps -ef | grep apache, and paste the result

Comment: corresponing line in /etc/passwd : "apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin"

Comment: have you changed the line in sudoers to /usr/bin/killall (or where your killall file is)? if yes, then please change /sbin/nologin in passwd to /bin/sh (or where you sh is) for user apache and then try doing sudo killall abc

Comment: I do all of those. but still not works. Is there need any command to restart or reconfig /etc/sudoers or /etc/passwd files?

Comment: for sudoers you should edit it with visudo command if you have it installed. Can you do su apache after you changed /etc/passwd ?

Comment: yes, I can do "su apache" after changing /etc/passwd, but the problem is not solved! :-(

Comment: what happens when you do sudo killall abc as apache? what is your killall path ($ which killall)? do the changes to /etc/sudoers stay after you exit the file?

Comment: when I do "su apache" in terminal and then type "killall abc", I get this error: "operation not permitted". and when type "sudo killall abc", it ask me the password!

Comment: what's the result of $ which killall

Comment: please change the sudoers line to apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/killall and try again

Comment: change all the lines "killall abc" in myscript.sh to say "sudo killall abc"